# Function return undefined value when function operation done?

Tags: javascript

After call getObject() function return undefined value.

```
function getObject(a)
{
    return
    {
        x : a
}
}

console.log(getObject());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After call `getFunction()` function return "undefined" value.

```
 function getFunction(a)
    {
        return
        {
            x : a
    }
    }

    console.log(getFunction ());
```

In come case JavaScript insert automatic semicolon after some specified place according to ECMA-262. 
Please take a details look here-
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9

Now your code show look like this-

```
function getFunction (a)
    {
        return  ;
         {
            x : a
         }
    }
    console.log(getFunction ());
```

You may correct your code in following way-

```
function getFunction (a)
    {
        return{
            x : a
    }
  }
  console.log(getFunction ());
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does not support line breaks except when you are specifying JSON:

```
function getObject(a)
{
    return {
        x : a
     }
}

console.log(getObject());
```

This is working for me. Note the first `{` is in the same line as the `return` statement